# How to disable Visual Studio 2012 pop ups?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, popup

If it makes difference, I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and coding in C#.

What really bothers me are these information windows that are displaying when I hold the mouse over the codes on editor page.

How can I disable those ?

[Screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSQ9X.png)

[Screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMubq.png)

Comment: The examples you've shown are specifically enums and strings. Are you actually asking for a way to turn off quick info for all types? Also, out of curiosity: why are you still using VS 2012?

Comment: ye i wanna turn it off for all types . any info coming up after holding the mouse on codes . i had some troubles with installing new versions with DVD . i tried to download new versions but they are bulky And because the internet is so expensive here i had to download and use an light version like 2012 . right now im just learning c# i don't think new versions are needed right now ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools -> Options ->Text Editor->select your Language .There you can customize the text editor(eg:Unchecking the Auto list members/Parameter information)

Comment: auto list is not what im looking for ... thats just suggests the methods variables and.... when your typing . i unchecked the Parameter information but its still going on

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys.
the Parameter information was effective too and i disabled it , but the main problem was **Quick Info** which you can disable at the following address...

You can manually invoke Quick Info by choosing Edit > IntelliSense > Quick Info, by pressing Ctrl+I, or by choosing the Quick Info button on the editor toolbar.

and this is the link of microsoft docs that helped me .
[docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense?view=vs-2019)